# \@ifundefined actually defines macros?

Tags: conditionals

Is it just me or is it a bit illogical that

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{chapter}{}{}
\makeatother
\ifdefined\chapter chapter\else no chapter\fi
\end{document}
```

returns *chapter*. So basically `\@ifundefined` actually ends up defining the macro (making it equal to `\relax`)

Comment: It's a well known side effect of `\@ifundefined`. If you use it once, then you should always rely on it afterwards.

Comment: shouldn't it be documented then? I did not see anything about it in `source2e` (might not have looked closely enough)

Comment: @daleif there really isn’t a comprehensive manual about class and package writing; i would put this nugget in such a place.  as things are, you're expected to “know everything” if you venture into under-the-cover coding, which is rather sad.  (i started making notes towards such a document, but it's a bit late to redo it all now, imho.

Comment: This is not about class and package writing, but rather a side effect of a kernel macro. Perhaps it is just something you need to know.

Comment: @daleif Section 11.3 of `source2e`: “true if `\NAME` either undefined or = `\relax`”. I believe that the behavior of `\csname...\endcsname` was considered “well known” by the developers, so not worth mentioning.

Comment: @egreg, yes but it does not say anything about `\NAME` being equal to `\relax` afterwards if it die not exist in the first place.

Comment: @daleif The TeXbook, exercise 7.7

Comment: Probably worth remembering what `\@ifdefined` is (mainly) for: deciding whether to define something or not. In that context, you _always_ end up with a definition, so the `\relax` side-effect is unimportant.

Comment: @wasteofspace There's a reason the docs for `expl3` are _much_ tigher! (Of course, in `expl3` we use `\ifcsname` so avoid this problem, but ...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It isn't illogical it is *historical*.  You compared with

```
\ifdefined\chapter chapter\else no chapter\fi
```

But that is an e-tex primitive added some years after LaTeX defined `\@ifundefined`.

The classic TeX way to make that definition (for a csname that you do not know in advance) is

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname chapter\endcsname\relax no chapter\else chapter\fi
```

and that *does* define `\chapter` to be `\relax` in the no chapter case (and is how `\@ifundefined` is defined).

---

Note that in LaTex releases from 2018 onwards the definition of `\@ifundefined` has been modified so that it no longer defines the tested command to be `\relax` if it was previously undefined.

Comment: Might be worth noting that in a context where expandablity is not required, you can use a group in the testing